# Redirect from a mapActivity to an Activity using Itemized Overlay

Tags: android

i have a map activity with some points of interest.I would like to move to a new Activity when the user clicks on a interest map point!Is that possible?In order to have these points of interest i m using a Itemizes overlay like this :

```
public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>
{
 private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
 private Context mContext;

 public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context)
 {
 super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
 mContext = context;
 }

 public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay)
 {
 mOverlays.add(overlay);
 populate();
 }
 @Override
 protected OverlayItem createItem(int i)
 {
 return mOverlays.get(i);
 }
 @Override
 public int size()
 {
 return mOverlays.size();
 }
 @Override
 protected boolean onTap(int index)
 {
 OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
 AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
 dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
 dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
 dialog.show();
 return true;
 }
}
```

and then in my main activity i m calling

```
List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
 Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.avatar);
 HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
 GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(379720148,237728327);
 OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Laissez les bon temps rouler!", "I'm in Athens!");

     GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(73185812,78480667);
     OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "Namashkaar!", "I'm in Hyderabad, India!");

     itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
     itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);

     mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
```

to get some text when the use clicks on a map point of interest!Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Place your code for opening new `Activity` inside `onTap()` of the `HelloItemizedOverlay` like this way:

```
protected boolean onTap(int index)
{
    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index); // can be used to send data
    Intent in = new Intent(mContext, NextActivity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(in); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Adil has answered place the new activity in the `onTap()`. Now since you want to move to a map with a different set of overlay items, you should pass these values through intent (or any other way) to the second map, which should populate the map from the points it receives in the `onCreate()` from the previous activity.
So this way you will only have 2 map activities, and depending on which values are passed via the intent to it, the 2nd map will use them for population of markers.
For adding points to the intent you can do something like this:
`toBargeMap.putExtra("point1", "your_geopoint_here");`
And incase you want multiple points to be passed you can try adding the above line in a for loop and giving a different key for each value:

```
    for(int i=0;i<list_of_geopoints.size();i++){  
       toSecondMap.putExtra("point"+i, bargeOverlay.get(index).getTitle());
    }
```

Where toSecondMap is the intent to the second map.Then Extract these in your 2nd map activity for populating.